# SQL where not in LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of email addresses in one table and a list of domains in another table. I want to query the email from the email table ONLY if their email doesn't have a domain set in the domains table.

```
email                               domains
------                              -------

a@google.com                       yahoo.com
a@yahoo.com                        ebay.com
a@ebay.com
a@gmail.com
```

So only a@google.com and a@gmail.com should be the result of the query.

The issues im running into is I have about 6 million rows in the emails table and it is taking substantially long to query even with proper indexes. Is there a better way to go about this? I also have a feeling using concat isn't helping because when you use a function it doesn't use indexes anymore?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
 email
FROM
    emails
    LEFT JOIN `domains` ON emails.email LIKE CONCAT( '%', domains.domain, '%' ) 
WHERE
    AND `domains`.`domain` IS NULL
```

Comment: Whatever you do, you will need to include the @ in your test, as your current join would allow a@spoofgoogle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a subquery like this:

```
select e.*
from email e
where not exists (select 1
                  from domains d
                  where e.email like concat('%', d.domain)
                 );
```

However, you might be able to get better performance with this version:

```
select e.*
from email e
where not exists (select 1
                  from domains d
                  where substring_index(e.email, '@', -1) = d.domain
                 );
```

The equality may make it possible to use an index on `domains(domain)`.

Comment: what if my domains table has the @ in the field? such as '@gmail.com' and '@google.com'

Comment: @user2570937 . . . Then you would have a different question.  This question clearly does not have `'@'` for the domains.  That could easily be incorporated into the answer, though.